# Can't overwrite compile-command

Tags: compile

I am having this in my init file to reset the compile command in the C mode, but when I run the `C-c C-c` inside C mode I will get the old command `make ...` meaning my new command hasn't been set. Why? Here is the code:

```lisp
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (set 'compile-command
         (let* ((file (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))
            (fname (file-name-sans-extension file)))
           (format "gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c99 -pedantic -o %s.o %s"
               fname fname))))
      0 t)

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") #'compile)))
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `(add-hook …  0 t)` the `t` means to add the hook *locally* to the current buffer. When you load a C file, it creates a new buffer, and that hook isn't active in the new buffer.

I believe you can solve the problem by removing the `0 t` from the first `add-hook` call. That ways it will add the hook globally, and it will run in new buffers.

Comment: But it still will be active only in C mode right?

Comment: Yes, c-mode-hook should run for all C mode buffers. However, `compile-command` by default is global to all buffers. You probably want to change this from `(set 'compile-command …` to `(set (make-local-variable 'compile-command) …` like the example from the help page for `compile-command`. That way it will set the value only in the current buffer and not affect any other buffers, and each buffer can have its own compile-command.